# Type of expression is ambiguous without more context error on implementing parse signup

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform, appdelegate

I am following [this](https://www.codementor.io/swift/tutorial/adding-twitter-facebook-login-parse-tutorial-ios) tutorial on how to implement Facebook and twitter signup with parse and getting this error

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more contexterror

on loginViewController.fields line

```
  override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    if (PFUser.currentUser() == nil) {
        let loginViewController = PFLogInViewController()
        loginViewController.delegate = self
        loginViewController.fields = .UsernameAndPassword | .LogInButton | .PasswordForgotten | .SignUpButton | .Facebook | .Twitter
        loginViewController.emailAsUsername = true
        loginViewController.signUpController?.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(loginViewController, animated: false, completion: nil)
    } else {
        presentLoggedInAlert()
    }
```

can anyone help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Well i figured it out to solve this issue and answering my own question just in case

Replacing

```
 loginViewController.fields = .UsernameAndPassword | .LogInButton | .PasswordForgotten | .SignUpButton | .Facebook | .Twitter
```

By

```
loginViewController.fields = [.UsernameAndPassword, .LogInButton, .PasswordForgotten, .SignUpButton, .Facebook, .Twitter]
```

as we don't use "|" operator anymore..